# .Split() in for loop not returning list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wrote a for loop that is supposed take win-loss records of a football team and split them, to get a value for games won and games lost. Unfortunately my split('-') command does not seem to be returning a list when used in the for loop I wrote.

The data set was picked up from wikipedia  and the data is within a pandas dataframe.

Here is how I got the dataframe:

```
test = pd.read_html('https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/
    List_of_Michigan_Wolverines_football_seasons')

year_football = test[-1].T.set_index(0).T.dropna(axis=0, thresh=3)
```

The list that I am trying to iterate through is:

```
#format W-L
win_loss = ['7–1' '6–2' '2–6' '1–7' '3–5' '6–2' '6–2' '3–5' '3–5' '6–2' '7–2']
```

Which I got by doing a bit of cleaning and then calling:

```
print(year_football['Conference'].values)
```

My for loop is:

```
wins = []
games = []

for season in year_football['Conference'].values:
        win_loss = season.split('-')
        wins.append(win_loss[0])
        games.append(int(win_loss[0])) + int(win_loss[1]))
        print(season)
        print(type(season))
        print(win_loss)
```

The output for the first member of the list is:

```
7–1 #print(season)
<class 'str'> #print(type(season))
['7–1'] #print(win_loss)
```

I cant figure out what I did wrong, .split() is working fine outside of the for loop. hoping is not spelling error. (Also running in Jupyter if that helps)

Comment: You are splitting on `-`, but your `season` contains `–` - see the difference? Not the same character.

Comment: `ord('–')` is 8211; `ord('-')` is 45.

Comment: And just to clarify, it *is* returning a list, it just isn't split where you want.

Comment: Can @Błotosmętek or DYZ please post an answer so I can delete mine

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize they were separate characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your for loop to split on that actual character

```
for season in year_football['Conference'].values:
        win_loss = season.split(chr(8211))  # I changed this line
        wins.append(win_loss[0])
        games.append(int(win_loss[0])) + int(win_loss[1]))
        print(season)
        print(type(season))
        print(win_loss)
```